# multiple static IP's on Iphone

Tags: networking, ip, iphone

I would like to set 2 static IP's in my iphone. is this posible?

To be clear, I'll give the example.

1) my dhcp gives me 10.248.8.xxx to be conected to the internet
2) I have a domotica system in 192.168.0.xxx of whitch i can not change the IP.
i've set my routher so when i connect to my whifi and set my IP static in the both ranges I can do what i want, but now i would like to combine the 2. it is posible with Windows.
also with IOS?

thanks in advance

Comment: Since you can't change that domotica system, can you change your router to match that same network (192.168.0.xxx)?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: The question is off-topic because it relates to iPhones.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only have one IP address per interface on iOS, and your iPhone only has one wifi interface, so you can't do what you want.